# Convert sound inside a video, from 5.1 to stereo, without image modification?

Tags: conversion, stereo, sound

2 days ago I had troubles with video conversion, today that's audio. Here is the problem, the converter I found ([see this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/5571/how-to-convert-large-imovie-imported-videos-preservig-aspect-ratio/5573#5573)) detects all my sources audio channels as different channels (like if they were dvd languages) :

[image]

The first chanenl is the left speaker, and the second one is the right speaker, all others are middle's one. When I convert my video, the output is stereo but I loose one speaker. Here is an image to understand :

[image]

I gave a different color to each channels of my source : as you can see, after output, only the selected input is used for both speakers.

I suspect this software not to handle 5.1 channels as source. Because this is the only soft I found that supports my image resolution, I need to keep it for video conversion. But I first need to convert dolby to sereo using another software.

Do you know a way to convert dolby to stereo, without altering video ?

**edit**: `ffmpeg -i <video>` command gives [this output](http://pastebin.com/zS0shenp).

Comment: Do you want to discard everything except left and right, or do you want to downmix (combine specific channels into left and/or right)? Which channels should go where?

Comment: I want to discard everything except left and right. I keep original files for HD purposes but there, that's for sharing. Thanks

Comment: You can do this with ffmpeg ([OS X static builds](http://www.evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/snapshots/)). It can copy the video, so no need to re-encode, and select specific audio channels for the output. If you show the ffmpeg console output of `ffmpeg -i input` I can give an example command.

Comment: Whoa, a command-line, I dreamt ot that! The output of this command is [pastebined here](http://pastebin.com/zS0shenp). There is yellow warnings about unimplemented channels, but all info are there anyway.

Comment: Shoudn't the audio 5.1 mix be remixed for stereo??

Comment: At least I wanted to preserve the left/right channels into stereo (with headset this looks very similar to original source), I am not experienced at all so I'm not looking for complex things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`amerge`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#amerge) and [`pan`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#pan) filters in ffmpeg to combine two mono streams into one stereo output:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:3] [0:4] amerge,pan=stereo:c0=c0:c1=c1" -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le output
```

or using `-ac` instead of `pan`:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:3] [0:4] amerge" -c:v copy -c:a pcm_s16le -ac 2 output
```

`[0:3]` and `[0:4]` refer to your desired audio streams as shown in your ffmpeg output. I just chose these as examples. There are other audio filters and options too, so there are probably several other ways to do this.

Comment: You are the man of my day.

Comment: @Ninsuo Glad it worked for you. I forgot to mention that if you want to switch the channel locations then you can simply switch the positions of `[0:3]` and `[0:4]` as in `"[0:4] [0:3] amerge"`.

Comment: Thanks I understood the command-line. For me that's `[0:1]` for left and `[0:2]` for right. Works like a charm.